# MySql: FIND_IN_SET does not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a stored procedure which has a string parameter. This parameter comes seperated, as `'759,760,761'`. In where clause I want to use it like this.

```
...AND REL.CountyId IN (FIND_IN_SET(REL.CountyId, '759,760,761') > 0)
```

But there is no returned data however there is row with 759 county id. Datas come if I delete this clause.

Here is my all sql code:

```
    SELECT 
    REL.RealEstateListingId,
    (SELECT 
            ImageUrl
        FROM
            realestateimage
        WHERE
            IsMainImage = 1 AND Status = 1
                AND RealEstateListingId = REL.RealEstateListingId) AS ImageUrl,

    REL.ListingNumber,
    REL.Caption,
    REL.M2,
    REL.RoomCount,
    /*CONCAT((SELECT Name FROM City WHERE CityId IN (SELECT CityId FROM County WHERE CountyId = REL.CountyId)),'/', (SELECT Name FROM County WHERE CountyId = REL.CountyId)) AS Region,*/
    REL.Price,
    REL.Creation,
    REL.CountyId
FROM
    realestatelisting AS REL
        INNER JOIN
    User AS U ON U.UserId = REL.CreatedBy
        /*INNER JOIN realestatefilterrelation AS RFR ON RFR.RealEstateId = REL.RealEstateListingId*/
WHERE  REL.Price  BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
   AND CAST(REL.M2 AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
   /*AND REL.CountyId IN (FIND_IN_SET(REL.CountyId, '759') > 0) 

  /*AND RFR.FilterContentId IN(FIND_IN_SET(RFR.FilterContentId, filterIds) > 0)*/
ORDER BY REL.Creation;
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET returns position of the first match, then you compare it to 0, this gives 1, so at the end you use REL.CountyId IN( 1 ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
...AND FIND_IN_SET(REL.CountyId, '759,760,761') > 0
```

in query might look like:

```
...
WHERE  REL.Price  BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
   AND CAST(REL.M2 AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
   AND FIND_IN_SET(REL.CountyId, '759') > 0
   AND FIND_IN_SET(RFR.FilterContentId, filterIds) > 0
ORDER BY REL.Creation;
```

[`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings.
>
> Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.

...so, number greater than `0` means "found".

Part with `in` is useless in this case unless you are interested in specific position in the list.