# mysql query when you have coma seperated string both sides

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello I have this problem where I have a list of ids like

```
ID= 1,2,3,4,5
```

and the field in the database has values like

```
3,4,56,34,1,2,3 // field name can be users
```

and now I want to select all the tables in the database which has any of the values in ID

I tried this with

```
 FIND_IN_SET
```

but it's not working properly

```
    FIND_IN_SET (users, $ID)
```

can anyone help me with this, please??

Comment: Redesign you DB

Comment: Please your query here which you tried?

Comment: Do you want to select Tables or Rows??

Comment: You might want to use the [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql: FIND\_IN\_SET does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102969/mysql-find-in-set-does-not-work-properly)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i have a problem with selecting some data from mysql database both side CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467971/i-have-a-problem-with-selecting-some-data-from-mysql-database-both-side-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE CONCAT(",", `users`, ",") REGEXP ",(1|2|3|4|5),"
```

Comment: This is actually working, but i want to get results only if all the values of ID matches with users . i tried using & insted of | but dosent works

Comment: you can store users in ascending order(1,2,3,4,34,56) and then use SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE  `users` REGEXP "1,2,3,4,5"

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
$ID = "(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)";
$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ID` IN " . $ID;
//Execute $q here
```